# Получить значение ближайшего элемента?

Tags: jquery

Есть такая верстка,

```
<a class="order" style="cursor: pointer;">
                               Заказать консультацию
                               </a>
                               <input type="hidden" value="Заказать консультацию" name="name_modal"/>
```

при нажатии `на class='order'` как получить значение рядом input с помощью jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нужен следующий элемент то сделайте так:

```js
$('.order').bind('click', function(){
  console.log($(this).next().val());
  
  // Что бы не сработал линк
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="order" style="cursor: pointer;">
  Заказать консультацию (тег `a`)
</a>
<input type="hidden" value="Заказать консультацию" name="name_modal"/>
```